# Non static method accessing static variable in C++

Tags: c++, oop

So, I am fairly new to C++ OOP and am stuck with this (trivial) problem.
I have a class definition with a custom comparator like this:

```
class Solution {
public:
    static int pos[30];
    static bool cmp(char c1 ,char c2){
        return pos[c1 - 'a'] < pos[c2 - 'a'];
    }
    string customSortString(string S, string T) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < S.length() ; i++){
            pos[S[i] - 'a'] = i;
        }
        sort(T.begin() , T.end() , cmp);
        return T;
    }
};
```

I get the error from the compiler

```
undefined reference to `Solution::pos'
```

I reckon this has to do with accessing static variable `pos` inside non-static method `customSortString` but replacing `pos` with `Solution::pos` still doesn't help.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: *I get the error from the compiler* -- not quite. It is your *linker* , not *compiler*, giving you this error.

Comment: A better solution here would be to get rid of the static to begin with. If you're learning about OOP, you should be learning not to use static.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist interesting , also I am reading the reason behind it :/

Comment: To be honest, I don't really see any reasons for classes here. C++ is not Java, where everything *must* be in classes. In C++ you don't have to use classes. If a problem don't require classes (like your most likely doesn't) then my recommendation is not to use them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - It looks to me like raw code from a training site (where one inputs the solution into an online textbox). Those often put one's code into a `Solution` class. It's a good way to deter solutions that rely on static data, if that is inadmissible.